# Is there a way to automatically collect data from other tabs within a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, tabs

I'm creating a large google sheet and part of the spec is that there's an index page that can reference other sheets. Which would normally be A ok however those sheets don't exist yet.
I've found some code for Appscript that can get the name of every tab in a sheet but is there a way of using that to then pull data from the other tabs?
Normally sheets are my thing but I'm a little lost with this one.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I don't even really know where to start. I've tried the basic of having the list in one column and then in the next column using ='B2'!C3 (example cells) but that is throwing up errors. Any ideas?
Here is where I currently am, I have the list of tabs auto generated and I'd like to work out a formula for D5 which will take certain information from cells within other tabs. I have tried the indirect formula as suggested by Tedinoz
[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsmxI.png

Comment: You can always use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach()` to loop through every sheet in the spreadsheet

Comment: I'm confused about what is your problem. `Is there a way to automatically collect data from other tabs within a Google Sheet?` What does this mean? We know that not all sheets have been created so why are we disappointed about the error generated by `='A5'!H5` (which is perfectly sound _assuming_ that there is a sheet/tab in your master spreadsheet named "A5"). Perhaps you want something like `=indirect("'"&C8&"'!"&D8)` (where C8="A5", and D8="H5"), or a similar version of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS())`? Would you please clarify what you mean by "automatically collect data from other tabs".

Comment: @Tedinoz When I say A5 I'm trying to refer to a cell which would have the tab name in it. As the tabs won't be there automatically they'll rely on someone creating one a tab for a new problem and then the formulas within the sheet should use the appscript code to get the name of the new tab. Using that they should reference specific cells in that tab for the contents/index. If that makes more sense?

Comment: `If that makes more sense?` Yes and no. "Yes" because I've done this myself in the past and one wants to "automate" as much as possible the retrieval of data from various sheets. But in so far as _this_ question is concerned "no", because it is completely hypothetical. Perhaps that it all you need to know at this stage, but we don't know the layout of the index page, and the data that is to be retrieved from the various sheets.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the task, suppose you have an index page (sheet, tab) as the first one in the spreadsheet. So you want to keep all other **sheet names** in column A and **content of their A1** cells in column B respectively. Also you want to automate the collecting process with no dependency on actual sheet names and their quantity.

I think you can't do it without scripting, because index page formulas need to refer to known sheet name(s). So consider the following script:

```
function collectSheetsInfo() {
  const SHEETS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var info = SHEETS.map(
    (sheet, index) => [sheet.getName(), '=INDIRECT(A' + index + ' & "!A1")']
  );
  info.shift();  // remove index sheet info-row from the collection
  SHEETS[0].getRange(1, 1, info.length, info[0].length).setValues(info);
}
```

The above script collects sheet names and appends a simple formula for each sheet. I hope that this basic example helps you to achieve your goal.